# Removing just one separator from Twitter Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have Breadcrumb that I have on every page.  I want to pull two of the breadcrumbs to the right, but I want to remove the separator before the first element that is pulled right.  I have searched and found ways to remove, or replace all of the separators, but not just one.

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">Merchandise</a></li>
        <li>Stickers</li>
        <li class="pull-right">View Cart</li>
        <li class="pull-right">Checkout</li>
</ol>
```

I want to remove the separator between the Stickers and View Cart.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I assume the breadcrumbs are generated dynamically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with pure CSS

```
.breadcrumb > li + li.pull-right:last-child:before {
    content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another CSS selector approach:

```
.breadcrumb>li+li:nth-last-child(1):before {
    content: " ";
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/124329

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the expected `li` that you want to remove the separator:

```
$('.breadcrumb li').last().addClass('remove');
```

then reset the before content of this `li` element only using:

```
.breadcrumb li.remove:before {
    content: '';    
}
```

**[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/124327)**

---

If you prefer pure CSS solution, then you can use `:last-child`

```
.breadcrumb li:last-child:before {
    content: '';
}
```

**[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/124336)**